# nested getJSON calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, nested, getjson

So.. I am new to this Javascript and using JSON. I am developing a webpage which in this case needs comments, then the current username.

In order to develop this, I tried to create a function that returns the username using the getJSON() method, but obviously that would not work. What I came up with instead was using nested getJSON calls.

Something like this:

```
$.getJSON(getCommentsURL, function(jsonComments){
    $.getJSON(getUsernameURL, function(username){
        jsonComments[0].deleteButton = (jsonComments[0].username === username)
        // programming logic
    });
});
```

Mainly, the reason why I need both information is described in Row 3 of the code sample.

The question I have is, is this implementation acceptable conventionally? It does work, but there might be a more appropriate way to do this implementation. The reason I care about conventions, and appropriate ways to do this, is not only for my own knowledge, but because it is a school assignment that requires the code to be clean and correct (not only that it works).

Very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Are there any console errors/output?

Comment: All works as expected, and console sends 2 get-requests with expected responses.

Comment: Well, to answer the question, that is the information I get from the console. So no errors in console.

Comment: Then I would say this is good to go, the only real thing I can think of is maybe using promises instead of a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use case for using jQuery's answer to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) - [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

```
var commentsPromise = $.getJSON(getCommentsURL);
var usernamePromise = $.getJSON(getUsernameURL);

// when both requests complete
$.when(commentsPromise, usernamePromise).then(function(jsonComments, username) {
  jsonComments[0].deleteButton = (jsonComments[0].username === username)
  // programming logic
});
```

Comment: This one does indeed look much better. I was looking for something like this, but couldn't find it. Thats the reason for the nested implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The approach at Question should return expected result, you alternatively could use `.then()`. You could also include `.fail()` or `.catch()` chained to `.then()` to handle errors. Note `return` statement within `.then()`

```
$.getJSON(getCommentsURL)
.then(function(jsonComments) {
    return $.getJSON(getUsernameURL)
           .then(function(username){
             jsonComments[0]
             .deleteButton = (jsonComments[0].username === username)
             // programming logic
           });
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown)
})
```

Comment: in my case, there is no need for the catch() or fail() functions. This way makes the code longer. Even though using other methods, it is still a nested getJSON implementation. Thank you anyway!